# How to use Linq Group By and Distinct for Treeview

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, treeview

I am reading my initial data from an XML file and returning it as:

```
 List<ReportItem> ReportMapItems = Database.ReadXMLReportMap();
```

The ReportMapItems is then read into ReportTree that serves as the base collection for a treeview:

```
ReportTree = new ObservableCollection<ReportViewModel>(
            (from report in ReportMapItems
             select new ReportViewModel(report, ReportMapItems))
            .ToList());
```

XAML

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding ReportTree}"  >                  
            <TreeView.Resources>
                                    <HierarchicalDataTemplate 
                DataType="{x:Type r:ReportViewModel}" 
                ItemsSource="{Binding Children}"
                >
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ReportName}" Width="150" />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Comment}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

                <HierarchicalDataTemplate 
                DataType="{x:Type r:NetworkViewModel}" 
                ItemsSource="{Binding Children}"
                >
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding NetworkIP}" Width="110" />                       
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding NetworkName}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>


                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type r:PrinterViewModel}">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding IPAddress}"   Width="100" />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding PrinterFullName}" Width="300" />
                         <TextBlock Text="{Binding Location}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </TreeView.Resources>
        </TreeView>
```

The problem is the treeview is creating a node for each report entry in ReportMapItems and thus showing the same report multiple times.

What I need is to produce ONLY ONE report node for each distinct ReportName and under this node produce ONLY ONE network node for each distinct NetWorkIP. An lastly produce ONLY ONE printer node for each PrinterFullName under its corresponding NetWorkIP and ReportName.

How would one use LINQ to normalize either the ReportMapItems or the ReportTree such that the TreeView shows the information correctly (in normalized fashion)????

Thanks in advance for any help.

Edit: As per request, here are the definitions of some of the classes. (This is not meant as a code dump, but unfortunately there are quite a few classes involved. If more information is needed, I will be happy to add it).

```
public class ReportViewModel : TreeViewModelBase
{
    private string reportname;
    readonly IList<ReportItem> reportitems;
    private ReportItem report;
    private IList<ReportItem> ReportMapItems;
    private ReportItem reportitem;

    // Each ReportViewModel is a level 1 node in the Tree. Each ReportViewModel should only have reportitems specific to the
    // report being modeled.
    public ReportViewModel(ReportItem reportitem, IList<ReportItem> reportitems)
        : base(null, true)
    {
        this.reportitem = reportitem;
        this.reportitems = reportitems;
    }

    public ReportViewModel(Report SelectedReport, UI.Network.PRINTERMAP SelectedPrinter)
        : base(null, true)
    {
        ReportItem r = new ReportItem { 
            ReportName = SelectedReport.ReportName,
            Comment = SelectedReport.Comment,
            IPAddress = SelectedPrinter.IPAddress, 
            PrinterDescription = SelectedPrinter.Description, 
            PrinterFullName = SelectedPrinter.PrinterFullName,
            Location = SelectedPrinter.Location,
            NetworkIP = SelectedPrinter.NetworkIP,
            NetworkName = SelectedPrinter.NetworkName
        };

        this.reportitem = r;
        this.reportitems = new List<ReportItem>();
        this.reportitems.Add(r);
    }

    public string ReportName
    {
        get { return reportitem.ReportName; }
    }

    public string Comment
    {
        get { return reportitem.Comment; }
    }

    public IList<ReportItem> ReportItems
    {
        get { return reportitems; }
    }

    // LoadChildren() is called only when the ReportViewModel is expanded by user clicking on '+'.
    protected override void LoadChildren()
    {
        foreach (Network network in Database.GetNetwork(ReportName, ReportItems))
            base.Children.Add(new NetworkViewModel(network, this));
    }
}

   public class NetworkViewModel : TreeViewModelBase
{
    readonly Network _network;
    readonly ReportViewModel _reportviewmodel;

    public NetworkViewModel(Network network, ReportViewModel parentRegion)
        : base(parentRegion, true)
    {
        _network = network;
        _reportviewmodel = parentRegion;
    }

    public string NetworkIP
    {
        get { return _network.NetworkIP; }
    }

    public string NetworkName
    {
        get { return _network.NetworkName; }
    }

    public string ReportName
    {
        get { return _reportviewmodel.ReportName; }
    }

    public IList<ReportItem> ReportItems
    {
        get { return _reportviewmodel.ReportItems; }
    }

    // LoadChildren() is called only when the NetworkViewModel is expanded by user clicking on '+'.
    protected override void LoadChildren()
    {
        foreach (Printer printer in Database.GetPrinters(ReportName, NetworkIP, ReportItems))
            base.Children.Add(new PrinterViewModel(printer, this));
    }
}

public List<ReportItem> ReportMapItems { get; set; }

 public class ReportItem
{
    public string ReportName { get; set; }

    // Report description
    public string Comment { get; set; }

    // Printer IPAddress
    public string IPAddress { get; set; }

    // The PhysicalAddress of a device is its MAC.
    public string PhysicalAddress { get; set; }

    // Printer description
    public string PrinterDescription { get; set; }

    // Full Name of the printing queue
    public string PrinterFullName { get; set; }

    // Printer location
    public string Location { get; set; }

    // Network IP
    public string NetworkIP { get; set; }

    // Network Name
    public string NetworkName { get; set; }
}

   public class ReportTree
  {
    public ReportTree(string reportName)
    {
        this.ReportName = reportName;
    }

    public ReportTree()
    {
        // TODO: Complete member initialization
    }

    public string ReportName { get; set; }

    readonly List<Network> _networks = new List<Network>();
    public List<Network> Networks
    {
        get { return _networks; }
    }
}


 public struct NETWORK
{
    public string NetworkName { get; set; }
    public string NetworkIP { get; set; }
}

public struct PRINTERMAP
{
    // the PrinterName is the name from the printer que
    public string PrinterFullName { get; set; }

    public string MAC { get; set; }

    public string IPAddress { get; set; }

    public string Comment { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    // Location is from the Device table, (not the printer que).
    public string Location { get; set; }

    public int Type { get; set; }

    public string Company { get; set; }

    public string Model { get; set; }

    // the DeviceName is the name from the NetBios.
    public string DeviceName { get; set; }

    public string Office { get; set; }

    public string NetworkIP { get; set; }

    public string NetworkName { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Hi Alan, can you post the classes for ReportMapItem and related classes. It's really hard to answer this question without knowing the setup...

Comment: @Marc Hi Marc. I've added some of the additional classes. I hope its enough as this tends to involve many classes for both the view models and their contained data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one situation that I believe the `System.Linq` team missed. However, thanks to our ability to create [Extension methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx), we can just create our own `DistinctBy<TSource, Tkey> IEnumerable` extension method:

```
public static IEnumerable<TSource> DistinctBy<TSource, TKey> (
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector)
{
    HashSet<TKey> keys = new HashSet<TKey>();
    foreach (TSource element in source)
    {
        if (keys.Add(keySelector(element))) yield return element;
    }
}
```

It's a very simple method that only returns distinct property values by using a `HashSet` to 'filter out' the duplicate values. You can use it like this:

```
IEnumerable<YourDataType> distinctCollection = fullCollection.
    DistinctBy<YourDataType, YourPropertyDataType>(d => d.PropertyToMakeDistinctBy);
```

Comment: Thanks! Would you apply this to the classes directly being displayed by the Treeview, or to the raw data, or both?

Comment: I would use this in a view model, or if you don't use MVVM, the code behind of the control that you want to display the distinct objects in.